# Prop 5.3.6.2 in higher topos theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Here are the necessary notations and the statement of the proposition. I don't understand why the underlined sentence is true. Are the horizontal morphisms Cartesian fibration?

I would appreciate it if someone could give me some hints.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two vertical maps are fully faithful, because $D\subset D'$ is, and it preserves $\mathcal K$-indexed colimits.

Therefore, the pullback of the right vertical morphism is also a full subcategory $E$ of $Fun_\mathcal K(P_\mathcal R^\mathcal K(C),D')$, and by the commutativity of the diagram, $Fun_\mathcal K(P_\mathcal R^\mathcal K(C),D)\subset E$ as full subcategories.

The statement that the square is cartesian is equivalent to the statement that this inclusion be an equivalence, i.e. that any object of $E$ be in the image of $Fun_\mathcal K(P_\mathcal R^\mathcal K(C),D)$. But objects of $E$ are exactly objects of $Fun_\mathcal K(P_\mathcal R^\mathcal K(C),D')$ whose restriction along $j$ lands in $D$, so this is equivalent to what Lurie claims.

Comment: Sorry, Could you elaborate more on why this square being Cartesian implies it’s homotopy Cartesian?

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote cartesian I meant homotopy cartesian.

Comment: Ok, I might get it. Since fully faithfulness is invariant under equivalence so at the start we can reduce to the case where the right vertical morphism is a fibration and still make sure the two vertical arrows induce full-subcategory relationships. thanks.